# Aligning text and checkboxes using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this.

[image]

I have reached here so far.

```css
.main {

}

.first {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  border-left: solid 1px black;
}

.second {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  border-left: solid 1px black;
}


.last {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  border-left: solid 1px black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.height {
  height: 50px;
}

 .row {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='first height row'>
       <div>Name</div>
        <div>Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class='second height row'>
       <div>Email</div>
        <div>Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class='second height row'>
       <div>Phone</div>
        <div>Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class='last height row'>
       <div>Extention</div>
        <div>Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not really good with CSS, but I think, there is a more programmatic way of doing this. instead of how I did it?

Also, I want to place 2 checkboxes on right as well, Do I need to do another div with flex? any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do? It's hopefully fairly self-explanatory but if not drop me a comment and I'll explain.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td:not(:first-child) {
  width: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label::before {
  content: "✔";
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.35rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #047579;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='nameShow'><label for='nameShow'>Show</label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='nameRequired'><label for='nameRequired'>Required</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='emailShow'><label for='emailShow'>Show</label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='emailRequired'><label for='emailRequired'>Required</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='phoneShow'><label for='phoneShow'>Show</label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='phoneRequired'><label for='phoneRequired'>Required</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Extension</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='extensionShow'><label for='extensionShow'>Show</label></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='extensionRequired'><label for='extensionRequired'>Required</label></td>
  </tr>
  </div>
```

As mplungjan points out, I'm showing my age. Here's a version using grid:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 50ch;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, fit-content(1ch));
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.container>div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label::before {
  content: "✔";
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.35rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #047579;
}

/* border radius additions */
.container {
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  
.container > div:last-child {
  border-radius:0 0 10px 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>Name</div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='nameShow'><label for='nameShow'>Show</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='nameRequired'><label for='nameRequired'>Required</label></div>
  <div>Email</div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='emailShow'><label for='emailShow'>Show</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='emailRequired'><label for='emailRequired'>Required</label></div>
  <div>Phone</div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='phoneShow'><label for='phoneShow'>Show</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='phoneRequired'><label for='phoneRequired'>Required</label></div>
  <div>Extension</div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='extensionShow'><label for='extensionShow'>Show</label></div>
  <div><input type='checkbox' id='extensionRequired'><label for='extensionRequired'>Required</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not very elegant to retort to 1990s markup when we have grid and flex, is it?

Comment: Sure, I'll do a grid one too :-)

Comment: why not flex? @Adam

Comment: It would be harder with flexbox as each container may behave differently on different rows so controlling row width would require a bit more css.

Comment: great, thank you jus last thing about the border-radius of the first and last divs? as you can see in my CSS i had to change a lot make them curve / circular

Comment: I've modified my post and added a couple of rules to the css grid one for the border radius. Hope this helps